# Select all buttons except one with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code :

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
    <button class="button" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
```

I would like select all buttons from div #filters except the only one with #sort, using jQuery's selector.

Currently I have this but it doesn't work :

```
$('#filters').not('#sort').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
...
    }
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: `$('[data-filter]')` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on button's id is not `sort` ...

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button:not("#sort")', function() {
...
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Your selector should look like this

```
$('#filters button').not('#sort')
```

```js
$('#filters button').not('#sort').css('background', 'blue')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
  <button class="button" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#filters button').not('#sort').on( 'click', 'button', function() {...} doesn't work. No button is recovered. It's my fault I did not say it was for use with function on( 'click' ...)

Comment: Yes because you changed this .on( 'click', 'button', function() into .on('click', function()

Answer (score 2):

You can use the :not jquery selector.

```
$("#filters button:not(#sort)").on( 'click', function(){...});
```

*Updated to reflect clarification in OP.

Comment: $("#filters button:not('#sort')").on( 'click', 'button', function() {...} doesn't work. No button is recovered. It's my fault I did not say it was for use with function on( 'click' ...)

Comment: @PierreDommerc You don't need to specify 'button' after 'click'. The single quotes around #sort might also be throwing it off. Try this: `$("#filters button:not(#sort)").on( 'click', function(){...});`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:not()` selector like :

```
$('#filters button:not("#sort")')
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#filters button:not(#sort)').prop('disabled', 'true')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
  <button class="button" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
```

Or you can filter using data attribute as mentioned in @Robiseb's comment :

```
$('[data-filter]')
```

```js
$('[data-filter]').prop('disabled', 'true')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
  <button class="button" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question because I I forgot to say to say it was for use with function on( 'click' ...) . Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
$('#sort').siblings('button').click(....)
```

Example:

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
    <button class="button" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#sort').siblings('button').click(function(){
            alert('I am not the sort button');
         });
    });
</script>
```

would do the work. This ensures only buttons inside of your div (siblings of the sort button) are affected.

Comment: I edited my question because I I forgot to say to say it was for use with function on( 'click' ...) . Sorry!

Comment: This still works that way, you just add the click function in the end to add a click event handler. I edited the answer to show an example

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, considering the id sometimes are not available, is:

select all buttons except the one with data-sort-value attribute:

```
$('#filters button:not([data-sort-value])')
```

Example:

```js
$('#filters button:not([data-sort-value])').each(function(index, element) {
  console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="filters" class="button-group">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".image">Photos</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".movie">Vidéos</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".text">Text Seulement</button>
    <button class="button" id="sort" data-sort-value="likes">Likes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question because I I forgot to say to say it was for use with function on( 'click' ...) . Sorry!

Comment: Do not worry. It is a pleasure you solved your problem. Thanks so much